# What scriptures describe the layers of the Earth mentioned by Engalalwan?

Tags: puranas, sri-vaishnava, lokas, vishnu-purana

This verse in [Amsha 1 Adhyaya 4](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp038.htm) of the Vishnu Purana describes the aftermath of Vishnu’s incarnation Varaha rescuing the Earth from the water:

> Uttishtatah tasya jalaardra kuksheh mahaa varaahasya maheem vigruhya | 
>   Vidhunvato veda mayama shareeram romaantarasthaa munayah stuvanti ||
>
> Through the indentations made by his hoofs, the waters rushed into the lower worlds with a thundering noise. Before his breath, the pious denizens of Janaloka were scattered[.]

Here is what the 11th century Sri Vaishnava Acharya Engalalwan says about this verse in his commentary on the Vishnu Purana, followed by U. Ve. A. Narasimhan Swami’s summary of the commentary:

> Prayaanti ityaadi | 
>  
>   Varaahasya khuraagrena vikshate videerne rasaatale sati, adhah anda kataahe prayaanti sma | 
>  
>   Kruta shabda santati iti kiyaa visheshanam | 
>   Tathaa cha shri vishnu dharmottare gangaa vyaaptou paataalaani adhikruti uktam * roukma bhoumaat adho yaataa roudram tejah sudaarunam | 
>   Tatra api avilayam yaataa varaaham lokamaagataa | 
>   Vaaraaha loke brahmaandam adha oordhve bhinnavaan harih | 
>   Chidrena tena saa devee svaam yonim punaraagataa |
>
> Rasaatala being torn apart, the waters started moving down in the anda kataaha. Great noise was made by the moving waters, when the Rasaatala got torn apart. Sri Engal Aalwaan quotes Vishnu Dharma, where Ganga came from Deva Loka to here, it went to various worlds. **Various layers of the earth are told - shveta bhouma, rakta bhouma, shilaa bhouma, rukma bhouma**. Crossing all of this, it came to Vaaraaha loka. Brahmaanda was torn apart into two halves by Hari. After that, He again came back to the original place.

I’m interested in the part in bold.  My question is, what scriptures describe Shveta Bhouma, Rakta Bhouma, Shila Bhouma, and Rukma Bhouma, the layers of the Earth alluded to by Engalalwan?

Note that I don’t want scientific speculation, I just want to know what scriptures describe these layers.

Comment: The answer is in the question. "Shri Vishnu Dharmottare". Also Engalazhvan just mentions "Roukma Bhauma etc". So I guess Vishnu Dharmottara Purana gives the detailed description, and the translator has taken the names from there

Comment: Yeah, the detailed descriptions, if they’re in the Vishnu Dharmottara Purana, is what I’m interested in.

Comment: Do you just want mentioning of them or also the detail description ? They are regarded among seven hell's in some scriptures but not much details like their physical appearance is mentioned.

Comment: They are mentioned in Nilamata Purana -Page 217 - https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.135304/page/n231

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Rakta means blood or red, while the last one means iron a sa noun, or gold-like in color. Silaa means rock I believe.

Comment: The comm. you have quoted and the translation isn't of this śloka but of the prev. śloka  (i.e. 1.4.28). https://archive.org/details/Vishnu_Purana_with_Vishnuchittiyam_-_PB_Annangaracharya_1972/page/n37/mode/2up?view=theater

Comment: I have given an answer to this question here https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/58649/24460 if you are interested you may check out. Thanks  @SwiftPushkar

Comment: @Haridasa Right, it's mentioning the color of bhūmis. Rakta is blood or red, raukma is golden or gold. Śaila is stone.

Comment: @Surya Viṣṇu Dharmottara Purāṇa being an Upapurāṇa follows the Mahāpurāṇas, and this info is already mentioned in mahāpurāṇas, as I point in my answer.

Comment: @Bingming similair to the layers of earth present in science such as a red molten layer and an inner hot iron core.

Comment: @Haridasa kinda, but here the colors, etc. are not of the layers of pṛthvi. Instead, it's of the different lokas.

Comment: @Bingming ahh okay

Answer (score 2):

The Vishnu Dharmottara Purana context mentioned by Engalazhwan only lists the names of these worlds. The verses are found in Chapter 1.22 also known as Ganga-Vyaapti or the Pervasion of Ganga. I'm reproducing the verses below:

> ekībhūtā praviṣṭhā sā bhogavatyām samīpataḥ।
>   śvetabhaumaṃ gatā tasmād raktabhaumaṃ tato gatā ॥30॥
>   śilābhaumaṃ gatā tasmād rukmabhaumam tato gatā।
>   rukmabhaumādapi gatā raudram  tejassudāruṇam ॥31॥

Comment: What is the translation of these verses and what is it saying about the layers?

Comment: I have given an answer https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/58649/24460 to the question by OP. If you are interested, you may check it out. Thanks @Sarvabhouma  & hashable.

Answer (score 2):

The OP has doubt regarding this śloka from [Eṅgaḷāḻvān's comm. on Viṣṇu Purāṇa (1.4.28)](https://archive.org/details/Vishnu_Purana_with_Vishnuchittiyam_-_PB_Annangaracharya_1972/page/n37/mode/2up?view=theater),-

> tathā ca śrīviṣṇudharmottate gaṅgāvyāptau pātālānyadhikṛtyoktam raukmabhaumādadho yātā raudraṁ tejaḥ sudāruṇam /

Here, Eṅgaḷāḻvān mentions Raukmabhauma, etc. lokas. The term 'bhauma' is from 'bhūmi' and refers to the earth or soil. There are seven adholokas (pātālalokas), and each of these have bhūmis of different types (such as color). So, these lokas are also known by the type of their bhūmi. For e.g. a loka with a bhūmi of nīlaraṅga can be called Nīlabhauma.

As per Viṣṇu Purāṇa ([2.5.2](https://archive.org/details/vishnu-puran-illustrated-with-hindi-translations-gita-press-gorakhpur/page/n135/mode/2up?view=theater)), the 7 adholokas are - Atala, Vitala, Nitala, Gabhastimān, Mahātala, Sutala, & Pātāla. The bhūmis of these lokas are- śukla (varṇa), kṛṣṇa (varṇa), aruṇa (varṇa), pīta (varṇa), śarkarā (sand), śaila (stone), and kāñcana (varṇa) respectively. [Viṣṇu Purāṇa ([2.5.3](https://archive.org/details/vishnu-puran-illustrated-with-hindi-translations-gita-press-gorakhpur/page/n135/mode/2up?view=theater))]. Since, Gabhastimān has pītabhūmi, it is Pītabhauma. Similarly, Atala is Śuklabhauma or Śvetabhuama, Pātāla is Raukmabhauma or Suvarṇabhauma, and so on.

As per Skanda Purāṇa ([1.2.39.1-2](https://archive.org/details/skanda-maha-purana-i-nag-publishers/page/n449/mode/2up?view=theater)), the 7 adholokas are Atala, Vitala, Nitala, Rasātala, Talātala, Sutala and Pātāla. Their bhūmis are kṛṣṇa (varṇa), śukla (varṇa), aruṇa (varṇa), pīta (varṇa), śarkarā (sand), śaila (stone), and kāñcana (varṇa) respectively. There is a slight difference in the lists of Viṣṇu Purāṇa & Skanda Purāṇa, as (Rasātala, Talātala) in latter is called (Gabhastimān, Mahātala) in former. And in the list of Skanda Purāṇa, the bhūmis of Atala and Vitala are reverse of that in the list of Viṣṇu Purāṇa.